# How to mount iso as a device

Tags: mount, iso

Before formatting my hard drive to dual boot a new install of both Windows and Xubuntu, I made an ISO of my whole SSD and put it on my data hard disk by doing this from a live CD: `dd if=/dev/sda of=/data/OldDisk.iso`. This means it contains all of the partitions on there and meant it would be easy to replace Windows (including the MBR etc.) if the whole thing went tits-up.

Now I would like to mount the ISO as a normal hard drive so I can mount a partition on that drive (or mount a specific partition on the ISO) so I can access some of the old files (specifically my music collection) that I forgot was on my SSD not my HDD.

How would I go about doing this?

P.S. XUbuntu is amazing on a powerful PC because the boot time is 2 seconds! Only use Win for some games!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use kpartx to create loop devices for each partitions inside the iso image, then mount the created devices. Following [Robert Penz blog](http://robert.penz.name/73/kpartx-a-tool-for-mounting-partitions-within-an-image-file/) explanation, you could type these commands in a terminal :

```
sudo kpartx -a /data/OldDisk.iso
sudo mount /dev/mapper/loop0pX /mnt/ -o loop,ro
# point your file browser to /mnt
```

and, when you're done

```
sudo umount /mnt
sudo kpartx -d /data/OldDisk.iso
```

In these commands, X is a partition number

Comment: Thank you so much. I couldn't find this anywhere on the internet! (Turns out I was searching for the wrong thing!)

Comment: Sure! It ws easier for me as I already knew what to search. Glad you could recover your files.

Comment: Didn't work for me... Got a device on `/dev/loop0` according to `kpartx -d /path/to.iso`..

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to find the file with nautilus (files), right click on the file and choose 'Open with Archive Mounter'

Comment: This doesn't work because it is not a partition or even a file system in the ISO but a whole disk.

Comment: @RX14  OK I can see that might be an issue.  Probably why I prefer rsync to make backups of my files.

Comment: But rsync doesn't copy the MBR does it? I wanted to do a simple `dd if=/data/OldData.img of=/debv/sda` if things went wrong! Rsync would mean I would have to make a new NTFS FS and fix Windows's boot!